# Serving React frontend and Flask backend using Nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I've been trying to set up a React frontend and a Flask backend using Nginx as a reverse proxy to differentiate the two. I have the flask backend running a Gunicorn server on localhost:5000, but I can't seem to get the Nginx location block to register it. My config file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/[react-app-domain-name]/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
  }

  location /api {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
  }
}
```

My understanding is that this should route all traffic through my react app at root, except for requests that have "/api", which should then be routed through my backend Flask api. However, when I try to access a /api route, all I get back is a 404 response. This also happens if I true to access it through curl on the command line.

Here's the 404 error log that I have:

```
2020/09/09 21:03:05 [crit] 36926#36926: *114 connect() to unix:/home/[name]/backend/backend.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://unix:/home/[name]/backend/backend.sock:/api/", host: "[hostname]"
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm tearing my hair out here. Thanks.

Comment: I use a similar setup for one of my projects. Try moving the line beginning with `root` and `index` within the scope of `location / {` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Just tried, didn't help unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'm wondering if I didn't gunk up some other setting somewhere that's throwing a wrench into things and I don't even know it.

Comment: Gotcha, what are in your proxy_params?

Comment: Have you added `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` to the end of your `package.json`?